# ncrack ssl option

Tags: tls, passwords, brute-force, nmap

There is the following option in `ncrack` (from the [man page](https://nmap.org/ncrack/man.html)):

> Misc options:
>
> ssl: enable SSL over this service

> ssl (Enable/Disable SSL over service)
>
> By enabling SSL, Ncrack will try to open a TCP connection and then
> negotiate a SSL session with the target. Everything will then be
> transparently encrypted and decrypted. However, since Ncrack's job is
> to provide speed rather than strong crypto, the algorithms and ciphers
> for SSL are chosen on an efficiency basis. Possible values for this
> option are 'yes' but just specifying ssl would be enough. Thus, this
> is the only option that doesn't need to be written in the
> = format. By default, SSL is disabled for all services
> except those that are stricly dependent on it like HTTPS.

What are use cases for this option?

Or is it just to upgrade modules like `ftp` to `ftps`, `http` to `https`,`pop3` to `pop3s` and so forth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options you provided are not equivalent.

#### HTTP / HTTPS

This is one of the things that would work with ncrack's `--ssl` option. Keep in mind that not every HTTPS server listens to port 443 exclusively. I've seen port 8443 (complementary to port 8080) being used, 9000, and some others as well. So if you want to use ncrack on a HTTPS connection on port 9000, the `-ssl` option is there.

#### FTP / FTPS

FTP and FTPS are fundamentally different from HTTP and HTTPS' relationship. While HTTPS is just "HTTP with SSL" (or TLS these days), FTP and FTPS are more complicated.

For **implicit FTPS**, it is indeed just FTP over SSL, which would work well with the `--ssl` option.

For **explicit FTPS**, sometimes referred to as "hybrid mode", the client explicitly has to the the `AUTH TLS` command to request an encrypted connection (hence, the name). I have no idea if ncrack supports that for FTP.

It's a similar story for POP3 and POP3S, which uses StartTLS.

## When to use `--ssl`?

Simply put, whenever you connect to a port which *you* know requires a TLS connection, but ncrack can't figure it out by itself.